# PhpSpreadsheet library save with directory

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I want to save the file in custom directroy

I get below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not open C:\xampp\htdocs\test3/wp-content/uploads/next_shoppingcart\shoppingcart_report_2021-12-13 17:43:00.xlsx for writing. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\wp-content\plugins\next-shopping-list\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php:218 Stack trace

the code is:

```
<?php
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$basedir   = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/next_shoppingcart';

if (!file_exists($basedir)) {

    mkdir($basedir, 0777, true);

}

$writer->save($basedir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name);?>
```

Comment: Does you OS allow filenames with spaces in and colons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape the timestamp. I.e shoppingcart_report_2021-12-13 \17:43:00.xlsx as my os sees the space as separating two filenames. You can echo out the date then append and echo out the time to be something like shoppingcart_report_2021-12-13-17-43-00.xlsx. the hyphen will make the time to be considered part of the same file. The comments are correct that you cannot have colons in the filename for native windows and linux

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you're trying to explain here. Windows doesn't allow `:` in a file name, no matter how you escape it, and the backslash character is the directory separator, not a escape character.